# WhatsApp Business Platform API using Test account doesn't send the message to Mobile

Tags: api, whatsapp

I have created a WhatsApp Business Platform Test account. I am able to send and receive the hello-world template message but when I send a test message without template(as specified by the api) it doesn't push it to the mobile phone. Strangely I get success response in both cases.

Url: https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/11ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/messages

Here are the jsons and their responses

```
{
   "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
   "to":"91ZZZZZZZZZZ",
   "type":"template",
   "template":{
      "name":"hello_world",
      "language":{
         "code":"en_US"
      }
   }
}

{
   "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
   "contacts":[
      {
         "input":"91ZZZZZZZZZZ",
         "wa_id":"91ZZZZZZZZZZ"
      }
   ],
   "messages":[
      {
         "id":"wamid.HBgMOTE3MjkwMDIxMzYwFQIAERgSMjZCRkQ3RDc0RjM0QkNEZZZZZZ=="
      }
   ]
}
```

In these case I successfully receive message on the mobile

```
{
   "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
   "to":"91ZZZZZZZZZZ",
   "type":"text",
   "text":{
      "preview_url":false,
      "body":"Hello World Testing"
   }
}

{
   "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
   "contacts":[
      {
         "input":"91ZZZZZZZZZZ",
         "wa_id":"91ZZZZZZZZZZ"
      }
   ],
   "messages":[
      {
         "id":"wamid.HBgMOTE3MjkwMDIxMzYwFQIAERgSQUJERkM2RUE1RTEwQTExZZZZZZ=="
      }
   ]
}
```

However I don't receive message on the mobile.
Is there anything I am missing in the second case?

Comment: The business can initiate template type message if the user replies then the business can send other types (text, media, etc.) of messages.

Comment: Predefined template message like hello-world is working fine. I am not able to create a new template as it seems a limitation on test account. But the issue I am facing is with a normal message without a template. I am not receiving it on my mobile

Comment: If you can understand my first comment, I said you can not send other types of messages but there is a condition if the user replies to you in 24 hours window then you can send other types of messages to that user.

Comment: Ah great! It worked. But the API doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: If you follow the getting started steps you will find it in [3rd point](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started#sent-test-message). => *Message templates are the only type of message that can be sent to customers who have yet to message you, or have not messaged you in the last 24 hours. Thus, message templates are primarily used to initiate conversations with customers*

Comment: Does this apply for real business account also? So does it mean that we always need to send a template message before sending any message. Actually we may be sending different message to mobile numbers and that could be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is not for only test numbers, that rule applies to all the business phone numbers, *So does it mean that we always need to send a template message before sending any message* => No, You can only send message when user message you in 24 hours window.

Answer (score 9):

I was strugging with the same problem, but I figured out that you need to reply back to your first template message with a 'hello' or any kind of reply. Once you reply, only then can you send a message through that watsapp api without a template, or you can inititate conversation through watsapp api.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works perfectly. Remember if user replies to that template you can send normal messages with whatsapp api

Comment: @ouflak - do you know the other way around? I have a business initiated API configured but unless my users says "hi" to the account, we are not able to send the Whatsapp Authentication messages.

Comment: @Ravi, Your question really is meant for the OP of this answer Arjun A. I *think* he gets pinged as well when you comment, but just to be sure you might want to just post a quick comment (don't need the '@').